# Send request to API with Space

Tags: c#, api, post, tumblr

I work with Tumblr API.
When i finished Authorization I realized sending a message on the wall.
The problem is, if you send a message as a single word, then all is well. But if I put a "space" between the messages, then immediately throws an error.

> {"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}

The request was replaced by special characters with help of Uri.EscapeDataString.

what could be the problem?

my request:

> {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/yakodev.tumblr.com/post', 
>   Version: 2.0, 
>   Content: System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent, 
>   Headers:{  Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", oauth_nonce="621273048", oauth_signature="QPfyHvu37iWiAABDmNkji5kqKbQ%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1453222553", oauth_token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", oauth_verifier="HRvgN8SMQjEqDrhCd8aKZRl5u8oMPyGo7n9E9NZdfBZjL0IaSD", oauth_version="1.0"  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  Content-Length: 25}}

and my body:

> title=test&body=Hello%20World

Comment: Post an example of what you are trying to send

Comment: @John update question

Comment: I suspect that you have to send the data as JSON, if that's not what you are already doing, depends from where you copied the body. Anyway, json then should be like this: {"title": "test", "body": "Hello World"}

Comment: @John i send data as
  postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("body","Hello World"));
  requestMsg.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

Comment: @John It may need "Space" be replaced by "+"?

Comment: Check https://tumblrsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Posting&referringTitle=Documentation